# KAFKA ListenableFuture spring- how to return client a response with object based on onsuccess method future.addCallback as onsuccess is void

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

```java
public class Test {

    public StudentDto publishStudentDto

    {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Student>> future = this.studentKafkaTemplate.send(topicName, student);
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Student>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Student> result) {
                logger.info("Student created & message published to topic: {} with offset: {} to partition {}", student, result.getRecordMetadata().offset(), result.getRecordMetadata().partition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                logger.error("student not created. Error in publishing student to topic : " + student, ex);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to return StudentDto to controller if Student is published successfully on topic. But as onSuccess is called after the response is returned to controller. Is there is any way i can return StudentDto if it published successfully.

I want to return StudentDto to controller if Student is published successfully on topic. But as onSuccess is called after the response is returned to controller. Is there is any way i can return StudentDto if it published successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an async listener, simply call `get(...)` on the future (with some timeout) and the thread will block until success or failure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ideally get(...) will block the other request at a time(for the timeout set). Could you please suggest which is the better approach to send record to kafka async with callback listener or the get on the future.

Comment: If you want to block the caller thread until the result is received, get is simplest. Async would mean you'd have to write code to block the caller and wake him when the result is received.

Comment: Can you help me with this one as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75780715/kafka-producer-producing-values-in-alternative-even-partitions-like-0-2-4-etc

Answer (score 0):

```
future.completable().join();
```

By using the above line of code and a small flag for updating the status, the main thread will wait until the callback is completed before exiting and you can compare the flag to return or leave it.

join() returns the result after the future is completed.