# Kafka producer producing values in alternative even partitions like 0,2,4...etc in org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RoundRobinPartitioner

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api, producer

Kafka producer producing values in alternative even partitions like 0,2,4...etc in org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RoundRobinPartitioner

I have 6 partitions & their are 6 concurrent consumer to those & following config `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RoundRobinPartitioner`. While producing the messages kafka only puts the messages to 3 partitions on alternative way. which is leaving the other partitions not being utilized & messages in queue for 6 concurrent calls as only 3 are being used.

How can i achieve equal distribution?
Is there is any config i'm missing?

```
props.put(partitioner.class, "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RoundRobinPartitioner");
```

I'm using org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka jar. And instead of providing key passing null key as in producer record. ie. Not passing any key just passing dto.
Below is the producer config :-

```
 @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Dto> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
 @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Dto> dtoProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = getProducerFactoryConfigMap();
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

 private Map<String, Object> getProducerFactoryConfigMap() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getBootStrapServers());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RoundRobinPartitioner");;
        kafkaConfig.populateSaslProperties(props);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, PRODUCER_ACK_CONFIG);
        return props;
    }
```

Comment: I can see many questions with the same issue on SO. Please check them first. Looks like a bug, known issue. Probably an upgrade to a newer Kafka clients version would help.

Comment: @Mar-Z I tried updating Kafka clients version to latest but it doesn't help. Same issue is still there.

Comment: @garyrussel Can you help me with this one.

Comment: You need to provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have added my code snippets in above question tag. Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: Code snippets are not enough; need an MCRE so it can be run locally to see what's going on.